# Implicit missing values to explicit missing values in SQL-server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a data table in a SQL-server that looks like this (generated in R):

```
df <- data.frame(            
week = c(1,1,1,2,3,3,3),     
id = c(12,13,14,12,12,13,14),
x = sample(c(100:200), 7))   
df                           
#>   week id   x
#> 1    1 12 199
#> 2    1 13 164
#> 3    1 14 145
#> 4    2 12 139
#> 5    3 12 130
#> 6    3 13 154
#> 7    3 14 127
```

Now, as you can see I have some implicit missing values for `id = 12` and `week = 2`.

I would like to write a SQL-query that turn these into explicit missing values like this:

```
#>    week    id     x
#> 1    1.   12.   199
#> 2    1.   13.   164
#> 3    1.   14.   145
#> 4    2.   12.   139
#> 5    2.   13.    NA
#> 6    2.   14.    NA
#> 7    3.   12.   130
#> 8    3.   13.   154
#> 9    3.   14.   127
```

What would be a good aproach to do this in SQL?

Comment: I'd consider a LEFT JOIN.

Comment: Generate kind of calendar table and LEFT JOIN, unfortunately SQL Server does not support LEFT PARTITION BY

Answer (score 1):

You can construct the rows using `cross join` and then `left join` to bring in values:

```
select w.week, i.id, s.x
from (select distinct week from sample) w cross join
     (select distinct id from sample) i left join
     sample s
     on s.week = w.week and s.id = s.id;
```

Note that in SQL, `NA` will be represented as `NULL`.